# Как удалить в терминале строку?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Собственно, уже не помню, как это образовалось, но хотелось бы избавиться от этой строки в терминале (она появляется при запуске: bash: /..../)

[image: скрин терминала]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, это прописано в .bashrc, поищите там.

Comment: при более глубоком анализе, обнаружил след rvm

Answer (score 2):

Проверьте `/etc/profile.d` скорее всего внутри будет скрипт, который и пытается запустить RVM.

Более подробно [RVM](https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы отстало:

```
mkdir -p ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Чтобы найти где и убить:

```
grep rvm ~/.bashrc
grep rvm ~/.bash_profile
grep rvm /etc/profile.d/*
```